# When will llblgenpro 3 support NHibernate 3

Tags: nhibernate, llblgenpro, llblgen

Google-foo is difficult when you're trying to find the answer to version support questions like this. So when will LLBLGen Pro support NHibernate 3? LLBLGen Pro 3.0 supports NHibernate 2.1. If I just use it for the POCO generation from my database, will there even be a need for formal support for NHibernate 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it already does according to http://twitter.com/#!/FransBouma/status/11364697534107648

Answer (score 3):

NH3 doesn't add changes in the mapping department, so NH3 is supported out of the box. :)